# What are the main arguments predicting a Soft Takeoff vs Hard Takeoff scenario and viceversa?

Tags: agi, ai-safety

Here I am referring to the term AI Takeoff as described [here on LessWrong](https://www.lesswrong.com/tag/ai-takeoff), with annexed "Soft" and "Hard" takeoff definitions.

I find that page to be biased slightly more towards the hard takeoff scenario in terms of citing further resources to read, so was wondering if someone could provide a more balanced overview of the arguments from both camps.